# official Docker image Magento 2

Tags: magento2, aws, docker

As part of opening a Magento 2 CE 2.2.6 store on AWS, we would like to know if there is an official Docker image with an image deployment guide on AWS?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no official image so far :(
However magento docs have instructions for docker development of enterprise version (magento commerce)

Ref: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/docker/docker-development.html